# I'm unable to activate the google ad setting on my website using the adsense plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My website has been verified by google using the adsense plugin for wordpress.
The statement after says the ad spaces will be blank until after my website review. Now I'm able to configure the ad placement on my web page and even have a preview showing the ads. But I'm unable to save the configuration. The error message it brings is;

Sorry we were unable to save your configuration. The request to your server failed with error code 403.

I want to ask what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running Wordpress version 4.7.2 on my own server.  I disabled [WordFence Security plugin](https://www.wordfence.com/) version 6.3.2, before I went into manage ads in the [Google Adsense Plugin](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3380626) version 1.2.1.  I added my ads where I needed to add them and checked to see if they were working.  Everything works fine.  I then proceeded to turn WordFence Security Plugin back on and everything still worked fine.

If you are looking into conflict resolution between these two plugins, I can tell you Google last updated their plugin 11 months ago, so you may want to start, [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-publisher/).